# Solve differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

How can we solve (if a closed form expression for f(x) can be found) the following first-order linear differential equation?

$$f'(x)=f(x)\cdot (\cos x+\tan x)$$

I have found that one function which validates this equation is: $$f(x)=\frac{e^{\sin x}}{\cos x}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**
Separation of variables yields
$$
\int \frac{f'(x)dx}{f(x)} = \int (\cos x + \tan x) dx
$$
and LHS integrates to $\ln f(x) + C$.

Comment: So, RHS integrates to $ \sin x + \ln {(\sec x)}$, ignoring constants because we already have $C$. Finally, we have $$f(x)=C_1 \cdot \frac{e^{\sin x}}{\cos x}$$

Comment: i think you get $\sin x + \ln |\sec x|$, and must carry the absolute value unless you restrict yourself to the interval where $\cos x \ge 0$...

Comment: Yes, you are right! So, RHS integrates to $ \sin x + \ln {\left| \sec x \right|}$, ignoring constants because we already have $C$. Finally, we have: $$f(x)=C_1 \cdot \frac{e^{\sin x}}{\left| \cos x \right|}$$

Comment: @Jason yes, indeed